# Нужна помощь в поиске хорошего оборота для "покидать производство"

Tags: семантика

Перевожу немецкий текст рекламного характера. В первом предложении написано "Завод выпускал... (такой-то) продукт для... (того-то и того-то)". В следующем за ним (перевожу дословно): "...(конкретизация продукта) покидали производство".

Меня не устраивает "покидало производство". Так и хочется написать "сходили с конвейера", но это будет чересчур вольный перевод, т. к. неизвестно, был ли там на тот момент конвейер.

Буду признательна за любые варианты.

Answer (score 1):

Как я понял, "[что-то] покидает производство" означает здесь, что "оно" было **выпущено** или **произведено** (или, в определённом контексте, **изготовлено**). "Выпускать" у Вас уже использовано в предыдущем предложении, тогда можно использовать глагол "производить" (либо поменять их местами).

Для более точного ответа нужно видеть оба предложения (хотя бы в дословном переводе).

Comment: Да, Вы правильно поняли. Согласна, что нужно было сразу написать предложения.

Comment: Исправляюсь. "...(название завода) выпускал плиты для частных кухонь и пищеблоков.  Печи из чугуна и фарфора для гостиных покидали производство.

Comment: @AllaGratschova Можно сказать близко к оригиналу "сходили с производственной линии" (это выражение — некий аналог "сходить с конвейера", оно достаточно распространено и не подразумевает особых ограничений на "линии"). Вы уверены, что в контексте не подразумевается "отгружались [получателям / на склад]"?

Comment: Отличный вариант! Спасибо Вам, @grizzly! Это то, что я искала в своей голове. P.S.: да, я уверена в значении "выпускать/производить".

Comment: Русский вариант предложения, скорее всего, должен заканчиваться существительным (здесь - продуктом), и это не будет вольностью, поскольку в немецком нейтральное положение глагола - в конце.

Answer (score 0):

Производство печей из чугуна и фарфора для гостиных сошло на нет.

Производство печей из чугуна и фарфора для гостиных осталось в прошлом.

Производство печей из чугуна и фарфора для гостиных было прекращено.